# Problema com caracteres acentuados (ADODB + MySQL + PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

Olá pessoal :D

Estou passando por um problema o desenvolvimento de um projeto onde eu não consigo colocar caracteres acentuados.

Estou utilizando para fazer a conexão com o banco de dados MySQL, o Adodb na versão 5.20.14.

Tenho um arquivo de configuração principal onde a conexão esta setada da seguinte forma:

```
$s_driver = "mysqli";
$o_db     = adoNewConnection($s_driver);
$o_db->connect($s_dbhost,$s_dbuser,$s_dbpasswd,$s_dbname);
$o_db->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC);
$o_db->setCharset("utf8");
```

Todos os arquivos desenvolvidos estão com a codificação UTF-8, conforme imagem abaixo:

[Image 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1HL6.png)

**OBS:** utilizo o VsCode.

Todas os arquivos PHP que são páginas, estão com o meta de charset setados como utf-8, conforme imagem abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Meu banco de dados esta configurado para utf8, conforme imagem abaixo:

[Image 04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkNFv.png)

As tabelas estão configuradas com o charset utf8, conforme imagem abaixo:

[Image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYd44.png)

As colunas estão configuradas com o charset utf8, conforme imagem abaixo:

[Image 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBQWY.png)

**OBS:** adicionei a regra de "NOT NULL" para ignorar tabelas que não tem a configuração de charset.

Na hora de executar a query para incluir a informação no banco de dados, eu rodo da seguinte forma:

```
$s_query_incluir = "INSERT INTO agtb_ordensdeservicos(id_agenda,
                                    id_empresa,
                                    hora_ini,
                                    hora_fim,
                                    observacoes,
                                    tipo,
                                    csa)
                        VALUES('".$a_post['add_id_os_dt_agenda']."',
                               '".ID_EMP_ATUAL."',
                               '".$a_post["add_os_hora_ini"]."',
                               '".$a_post['add_os_hora_fim']."',
                               '".$a_post['add_observacao']."',
                               '".$a_post['add_os_tipo']."',
                               '".$a_post['add_os_csa']."');";

$o_db->execute($s_query_incluir);
```

**OBS:** no topo do arquivo eu faço o include do arquivo de configuração que contém as informações mostradas na primeira imagem.

Após efetuar essa operação, o banco de dados mostra a informação assim:

[Image 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D97Bt.png)

Na hora de visualizar a informação no site, aparece da seguinte forma:

[Image 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkAg3.png)

Sendo que o texto original é esse:

[Image 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrWrn.png)

Eu consegui fazer funcionar adicionando o "setCharset" antes de dar o "execute" na query, conforme imagem abaixo:

```
$s_query_incluir = "INSERT INTO agtb_ordensdeservicos(id_agenda,
                                    id_empresa,
                                    hora_ini,
                                    hora_fim,
                                    observacoes,
                                    tipo,
                                    csa)
                        VALUES('".$a_post['add_id_os_dt_agenda']."',
                               '".ID_EMP_ATUAL."',
                               '".$a_post["add_os_hora_ini"]."',
                               '".$a_post['add_os_hora_fim']."',
                               '".$a_post['add_observacao']."',
                               '".$a_post['add_os_tipo']."',
                               '".$a_post['add_os_csa']."');";
$o_db->setCharset("utf8");
$o_db->execute($s_query_incluir);
```

Conseguindo o seguinte resultado no MySQL:

[Image 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODf5I.png)

Gostaria de entender onde eu estou errando. Estou tentando deixar o utf8 "automático" sem que eu precise ficar chamado o "setCharset" antes de qualquer tipo de execução de query.

Agradeço qualquer tipo de ajuda. :)

**OBS:** se precisar de mais informações sobre o processo para entender melhor o problema, é só me avisar.

Comment: Como é o resultado da query no terminal? Também com erro de codificação?

Comment: Você quer dizer na consulta? Coloquei no arquivo principal uma query com um "select" de teste e o carácter "é" é apresentado normalmente na tela. Rodando essa mesma query no MySQL Workbench, é apresentado o carácter "é" como "Ã©". Se eu for no próprio Workbench e alterar esse registro "Ã©" para "é" e consultar no PHP, fica com o carácter como "?".

Comment: Já tentou inserir no banco uma linha com strings PHP, sem utilizar o conteúdo do $_POST? Tenta também tratar o conteúdo que veio do $_POST usando a função utf8_decode().

Comment: @wensiso, No arquivo que faz a inclusão da informação no BD e que recebe o conteúdo do $_POST, criei uma variável para teste colocando como conteúdo o "é" e inclui no BD. Aparece como "Ã©". Se eu utilizar o "utf8_encode" na informação recebida, no banco de dados aparece como "ÃƒÂ©". Se eu utilizar o "utf8_decode", no BD aparece corretamente o "é". Pelo o que eu pude perceber, a informação esta chegando no banco de dados como algo diferente de "UTF-8", por isso o "é" aparece como "Ã©". Se eu alterar o "Ã©" por "é" direto no BD, no PHP a consulta do valor aparece normal como "é".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identifiquei o motivo do problema.

Mesmo configurando o banco de dados, tabelas e colunas para UTF-8/utf8_general_ci e o arquivo do PHP em UTF-8, o problema de caracteres estranhos permanecia.

O problema estava nas funções padrões do PHP que formatam texto, entre elas:

```
strtolower()
strtoupper()
ucfirst()
ucwords()
```

Ao executar essas funções em textos com acentuação, o retorno delas acabava se perdendo.
Após retirar essas funções de todo o meu projeto, o problema de caracteres estranho no banco de dados parou de ocorrer (incluir e consultando pelo PHP e através do MySQL Workbench).

Espero que isso possa ajudar outras pessoas que acabam passando pelo mesmo problema que eu. :)

**OBS:** demorei para responder pois só consegui validar essas informações após colocar essas alterações em ambiente de produção.

Answer (score 0):

Ola, tudo bem.

Confere o defaul_charset no php.ini.

É importante verificar também a fonte dos dados desse $_POST. se for um formulário, tenta interceptar a variável pra ver se ela já chega incorreta no servidor. Se for um arquivo, checa o encoding do arquivo.

E sempre temos a possibilidade de usar funções de encoding como utf8_encode() ou utf8_decode(), no seu caso, acredito que seja a segunda.

Abs

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Verifiquei no PHP.ini e o parâmetro "default_charset" não existe. Dei uma olhada na documentação do PHP.net e o valor padrão é "UTF-8" a partir do PHP 5.6.0 (no meu caso é o 7.3.14). Acredito que no caso do PHP.ini não teria problema (posso estar errado rs).

Dei uma olhada no phpinfo() e o valor de default_charset esta como "UTF-8" no master e local value.

Utilizo o AJAX via jQuery. No arquivo PHP que recebe a informação, rodei a função mb_detect_encoding recendo a informação do POST e aparece como UTF-8.

Comment: Todos os arquivos que fazem parte do projeto estão codificados em UTF-8. Gostaria de evitar a utilização do "utf8_encode" e "utf8_decode" a todo o momento sempre que eu for inserir ou consultar uma informação no banco de dados.

Comment: Olá, Allan, te entendo perfeitamente... Mas uma coisa é o que a gente gostaria de fazer e outra coisa é o que a gente precisa fazer rsrsrs. Se utilizando utf8_decode resolve o problema, é melhor usar, colocar como resolvido e partir pra próxima... talvez seja melhor fazer isso do que perder muito tempo tentando resolver um bug de encoding do banco... essa é a minha opinião. Boa sorte no seu projeto!